# Not able to get a response from Postman Echo service using Spring Cloud Feign

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-restcontroller, spring-cloud-feign

Have the following REST API that I would like to consume using Spring Cloud Feign. Seems like the REST call is happening but the values are not getting populated in the POJO.

**REST API:**

https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2

**REST Response:**

```
{
    "args": {
        "foo1": "bar1",
        "foo2": "bar2"
    },
    "headers": {
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "host": "postman-echo.com",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-605f6031-2ed4ef5d694c9f244286dada",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.26.10",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "postman-token": "3f849e3d-e6bd-44b4-bb82-8eea85e5b82b",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
    },
    "url": "https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2"
}
```

After integrating the above REST service into my application and call it through the controller, I see that the POJO is not getting populated.

```
http://localhost:8082/postman/echo
```

**Response (through my rest controller that uses Feign)**

```
{
  "args": {
    "foo": null,
    "bar": null
  }
}
```

**PostmanEchoClient.java**

```
@FeignClient(name = "postmanEchoClient", url = "https://postman-echo.com")
public interface PostmanEchoClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2")
    PostmanEchoResponse getPostmanEcho();

}
```

**PostmanEchoResponse.java**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PostmanEchoResponse {
    private Args args;
    private Headers headers;
    private String url;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Args {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Headers {
    private String xForwardedProto;
    private String xForwardedPort;
    private String host;
    private String xAmznTraceId;
    private String userAgent;
    private String accept;
    private String postmanToken;
    private String acceptEncoding;
}
```

**PostmanFeignController.java**

```
@RestController
public class PostmanFeignController {

    @Autowired
    PostmanEchoClient postmanEchoClient;

    @GetMapping("/postman/echo")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPostmanEcho() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(postmanEchoClient.getPostmanEcho());
    }

}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-feign-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>product-feign-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why do you use `foo1` and `foo2` in the URL, but `foo` and `bar` in the `Args` class?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That was the issue indeed. I didn't notice that because it was auto generated.